# Git push - Who can see the code of my project?

Tags: github

Do anyone who visit my git repo / account can see all the files I created and pushed them with `git push`?

My project is not open source, and I do not wish to share the code with anyone..

Couldn't find any information about it in google.

Comment: By defualt your acc is public. It can be seen by anyone. 
But you can create private account that will not be visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github code is public unless choosing the option for private from the setting for a private repo.
Private Repos are Repos in which your code remains private. Nobody other than you and the other collaborators can see it.

Comment: What about Microsoft, the owner of github?  Can they see code in private repos or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you repository isn't private anyone can view your code.

Answer (score 0):

When this question was asked in 2016, yes, if you had free GitHub account then you would only had public repos where everyone could see your code.
Now it's changed, using free account on GitHub you can create as much private repos as you want.